# How to get Accelerometer value in Android XAML App(Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to get accelerometer value at this point in code

```cs
private async Task GetValues()
{
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;

    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);

    //Get accelerometer value here
    var accX = 
    var accY = 
    var accZ = 
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong at any place. I don't any experience of using Xamarin neither I have done any mobile development before. I just want to get phone's GPS and accelerometer values and send them to a web service. Any other way of doing this task would be highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

use the [Accelerometer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/accelerometer?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms) plugin instead

```
Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometer_ReadingChanged;

void Accelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Reading;
    Console.WriteLine($"Reading: X: {data.Acceleration.X}, Y: {data.Acceleration.Y}, Z: {data.Acceleration.Z}");
    // Process Acceleration X, Y, and Z
}
```